# How to use return from a function properly in c#

Tags: c#, .net, return, return-value

I Want to return a variable from a function .I have done in the following manner .

my need is i want to split a sentence and check whether a specific keyword is exist or not .if yes it should return buy else sell

```
private string FindDirection(string Order)
    {
        string direction;
        string[] splitText = Order.Split(' ');
        foreach (string s in splitText)
        {
            if (Convert.Contains(s))
            {
                direction = "B";
            }
            else
            {
                direction = "S"; 
            }
            return direction;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

I want to return direction from the function. If i didnt put return null, it shows error. If i put return direction instead of return null,it shows "

> use of unassigned variable"

i am new here and f you have any suggestions in my code and style, please let me know.

Comment: think about the following case: you input an empty string and your loop doesn't get executed even once. _then what's the value of `direction`_?

Comment: This function probably does not do what you want it to do. The problem is, you never told us what you want it to do. Please tell us what you want this function to do in plain English and give us some example values (input, expected output).

Comment: @FranzGleichmann singleOrder always contain a value .never be null.

Comment: @nvoigt in my foreach loop it will either hit on if statement  or else statement.so direction contains always a value

Comment: @john The compiler cannot know what will happen at runtime. You declared "null" or `string.Empty` a possible input value by saying it's a `string`, so the compiler has to figure out what should happen if it's one of those.

Comment: If you're using "foreach" with `string s`,  then singleOrder should be `List<string>` or `string[]` not "string". Also it looks like your loop will return after 1 iteration.

Comment: @nvoigt so you said that this is a right way because if something happen to foreach loop it should return a null or empty value because it cant send a direction value.right?

Comment: Again: I can only see what your code does *right now* and I'm sure it's not what you want. Since you still have not told us what you **want** your code to do, preferably with example input and output, there is nothing we can do for you really.

Comment: @nvoigt let consider singleOrder ={apple,orange ,grapes,rose}  and strConvert ={rose,jasmine} .if singleorder array contain any string from strConvert it should return "buy" else "sell..

Comment: sorry my bad i have missed one line .i want to split the string so that i have to use foreach.  string[] splitText = singleOrder.Split(' ');.updated the code

Comment: @john _"what if"_... think about _what_ happens _if_ your input is empty. because that's what the compiler has to think about.

Comment: i have already done a null check for singleOrder.if singleOrder contains a valid value it will execute this function

Comment: The compiler doesn't know what you did before you call this function, so it has to assume the worst. After all, you could call  this function from multiple places (maybe not now, but in some future) and can the compiler be sure that you do that check every time before those calls?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing thanks. i have added the following line  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(singleOrder)) {
   // code here
}

Answer (score 1):

In your code sample, you would always return from the loop early, having only looped around the first string in splitText.

Place your return at the end of the function, allowing the loop to iterate over all its elements.

```
private string FindDirection(string singleOrder)
{
    string direction = "SELL";
    string[] splitText = singleOrder.Split(' ');

    foreach (string s in splitText)
    {
        if (strConvert.Contains(s))
        {
            direction = "BUY";
            break;
        }
    }

    return direction;
}
```

It would also be better to use an enum instead of a string for "BUY" and "SELL"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum

Comment: thankx. seems like it may work